# I want to use Django template language with JavaScript syntax

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-models, django-forms

So, I want to get user input from my form (addDatabase.html) and display output of what they entered and let them download txt file with yaml formatted output (output.html).

It was working when I used Django's models.py using request.POST["fieldname"].
What I did was using JS to grab the tag of innerHTML and display out put of it

**output.html JS code**

```
        var name = document.getElementById("name");
        formContents += name.innerHTML + "\n";


        var type = document.getElementById("type");
        formContents += "  " + type.innerHTML + "\n";
```

But my problem now is since I decided to use form.py using modelform instead of model.py. I don't know how to retrieve data from my model like i did from my model before.

**output.html**

```
<li id="type">type: {{ form.type}}</li>
<li id="vlanid">vlan_id: {{ form.vlan_id}}</li>
<li id="rdp">rdp: {{ form.rdp}}</li>
<li id="subnet">subnet:</li>
```

**View.py (using Model from models.py)**

```
def output(request):
    Form_info.objects.all()

    print("The button is clicekd")
    name = request.POST["name"]
    type = request.POST["type"]
    vlan_id = request.POST["vlanid"]
    rdp = request.POST["rdp"]

    ip_master = request.POST["ipmaster"]
    ip_backup = request.POST["ipbackup"]
    vip = request.POST["gateway"]
    nat_ip = request.POST["natip"]

    cidr = request.POST["cidr"]
    dns = request.POST["dns"]

    dhcp = request.POST["dhcp"]
    dhcp_pool_start = request.POST["dhcpstart"]
    dhcp_pool_end = request.POST["dhcpend"]

    form_info = Form_info(name=name, type=type, vlan_id=vlan_id, rdp=rdp, ip_master=ip_master, ip_backup=ip_backup,vip=vip, nat_ip=nat_ip, cidr=cidr, dns=dns, dhcp=dhcp, dhcp_pool_start=dhcp_pool_start,dhcp_pool_end=dhcp_pool_end)

    form_info.save()

    context = {
       'form': form_info
    }

    return render(request, 'niro/output.html')
```

****View.py using modelform from forms.py****

This is my previous addDatabase function

```
def addDatabase(request):
    # if this is a POST request we need to process the form data
    return render(request, 'niro/addDatabase.html')
```

This is my current AddDatabase function

```
def addDatabase(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = YamlForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()

        # return HttpResponseRedirect('niro/output.html', {'form': form})
        return HttpResponseRedirect('.', {'form': form})
    else:
        form = YamlForm()

    return render(request, 'niro/addDatabase.html', {'form': form})
```

addDatabase.html 
So post in here redirect to output.html function when the button is clicked

```
  <div class="container">
 <form action="{% url "output" %}" method="post"> 
{% csrf_token %}

<div class="row name">
<h3>NETWORK</h3>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-25">
    <label for="">NAME:</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-75">
      <span class="text-danger" small>{{ form.name.errors }}</span>
        {{ form.name }}

  </div>

</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-25">
    <label for="type">TYPE:</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-75">
    <span class="text-danger" small>{{ form.type.errors }}</span>
      {{ form.type }}



.
.
.
.
    <div class="row button container">
    <div class="row button">
        <button type="submit" value="submit">SUBMIT</button>
        <button type="submit" value="submit">ADD MORE</button>

    </div>
</div>
```

Models.py

```
BOOLEAN_CHOICES = (
(None, ' '),
(True, 'true'),
(False, 'false')
)


class Form_info(models.Model):
 # all the columns

# example = models.CharField(null=Ture, unique=True)
name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
type = models.CharField(max_length=1, null=True)
# vlan_id = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=0, null=True)
vlan_id = models.CharField(max_length=4, null=True)
rdp = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True)

ip_master = models.CharField(max_length=15, null=True)
ip_backup = models.CharField(max_length=15, null=True)
# vip = models.GenericIPAddressField(protocol="ipv4")
vip = models.CharField(max_length=15, null=True)
nat_ip = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True)

# subnetmask might be devided into 2 different fields
cidr = models.CharField(max_length=18, null=True)
dns = models.CharField(max_length=15, null=True)

# boolean dropdown doesnt show
dhcp = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=10)
dhcp_pool_start = models.CharField(max_length=15, null=True)
dhcp_pool_end = models.CharField(max_length=15, null=True)


def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('niro:output', kwargs={'pk': self})

def __str__(self):
    print("This is models.py")
    return self.name + self.name + self.vlan_id + self.rdp + self.cidr + self.dhcp
```

So I want to modify my views.py on both functions so that way I can display userinput from the form and enables download function with existing JS code using Django modelform. Please help me!!

Comment: So, what exactly is happening? You have 2 approaches, and one is not working? What's not working exactly; the rendering? The POSTing?

Comment: @wholevinski Hello! So Like I added above, I was just using models.py not using forms.py but I decided to use forms.py because it has more built-in functions. So my previous addDatabase function just had a form and redirect output to output.html and output.html(with models.py) did retrieving each input from the form with Form_info.objects.all() and name = request.POST["name"] etc... But I want to use ModelForm and modify my both views.. I was able to display output of userinput and download the same output but now I dont get any userinput but just blank when I submit the form..

Comment: So, after POSTing, `addDatabase.html` doesn't show what the user previously POSTed?

Comment: It still shows my html form but problem is it is supposed to redirect to output.html page when submit button is clicked and display output.. It won't display anything and when I download the file, it just gives me html code instead of userinput. So before, I literally had nothing in addDatabase function since it just display my form and got userinput but not it is doing posting all all the stuff, it got messed up :(

Comment: You can't send context information in an `HttpResponseRedirect`. Just call render on `output.html` and pass in your context instead of trying to redirect.

Comment: So addDatabase should be just raw html template where users input data but I made it template  {{form.filedname}} because I want to validate userinput and output.html should show the ouput of userinput

Comment: I was able to fix it but got into another problem...:'( but thank you for your help!